# What would cause males to develop sentience and females to Remain mindless?

Tags: biology, technology

Is it possible for a way for males to develop intelligence on par with computers and females to be mindless and only purpose is to reproduce ova for males similar to how male bees only purpose is to provide sperm and die?

Comment: If all the eggs are in a bank somewhere, where does conception take place?

Comment: The normal way or artificial insemination I just added egg banks for when a man is ready to have kids with a woman

Comment: If in vitro, then the only person present would be the lab technician who fertilised the egg. Why would a paternity test be needed at that point, I don't understand what you're asking. What would constitute "the normal way" if no women have eggs in their bodies. Please clarify.

Comment: Not all men do in vitro it's just a decision for the man if he has fertility issues

Comment: What's wrong with current state of the art paternity tests? How is this a worldbuilding problem?

Comment: I'm looking for a faster more advanced method that ours paternity test

Comment: Then what's the technology level of your world?

Comment: Just a noite: Nothing particularly noticeable happens "as soon as conception"; there is nothing to test. Specifically, the woman is not even pregnant yet. The woman becomes pregnant only if the embryo successfully [implants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implantation_(embryology)) to the wall of the uterus; if the product of conception is lucky, this happens about eight of nine days after fecundation.

Comment: The word for today brought to you by @AlexP is fecundation  Sorry, shades of Sesame Street seem to be creeping in around the edges there 

Comment: The edited version of the question is now extremely broad and undefined. "males to develop intelligence on par with quantum computers" doesn't tell us anything about their real-world capability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eugenics practiced by a horrendously sexist patriarchal society. I.e., what Larry Niven's Kzin did to themselves.

Only let the most intelligent males and least intelligent females reproduce. How effective that is will depend on the chromosomal distribution of genes related to intelligence (among other very complicated factors), but keep it up long enough and eventually you'll get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Gentic manipulation. Combined with controlled education.   Genetically speaking  men are more likely to be genius and are more likely to be idiots compared to women.  So if the woman's average intelligence Is that of an idiot level then the average man will be the same and some of them far lower.

Because of this I don't see this situation being possible without genetic manipulation. Controlled education also might work denying women the ability to learn to read write or even speak proper language.